# Create Ubuntu image without USB or Rebooting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, images, snapshot

I want to create a backup image or a snapshot of my Linux Ubuntu 22.04.1 system. Is there any way to do it without using USB stick, rebooting the system.. Basically, do it in the 'background' while I'm still using the PC?

I'm a beginner in Linux, anything helps. Thanks!